# Inner join not returning valid records

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 table as event_master,events as

1. event_master

> ```
> id subject location
> 1  Test    Test
> ```

1. events

> ```
> event_id event_master_id from_user_id to_user_id status
> 1                1           100          100       1
> 2                1           100          101       1
> ```

I write the following code to fetch records,

```
"SELECT *  FROM event_master as em
           INNER JOIN event as e
           ON em.Id = e.event_master_id
           WHERE em.Id = e.event_master_id AND (e.from_user_id = '100' OR e.to_user_id = 100) and e.status = 1"
```

It gives me 2 records, what i need is only 1 record and that will be where from_user_id and to_user_id is same, and if not then look for to_user_id

Answer (score 1):

If you want the record where to and from are the same, or else the record for the to user, why not just filter for the to user:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  event_master as em 
  INNER JOIN event as e ON em.Id = e.event_master_id 
WHERE 
  em.Id = e.event_master_id AND 
  e.to_user_id = 100 and 
  e.status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `em.Id = e.event_master_id` in the `WHERE` clause is redundant, you already checked it in the `ON` clause!

Besides that, here's what's happening.

You say

```
event_master AS em INNER JOIN event AS e
ON em.id = e.event_master_id
```

This gives you the following table:

```
em.id em.subject em.location e.event_id e.event_master_id e.from_user_id e.to_user_id e.status
1     Test       Test        1          1                 100            100           1
1     Test       Test        1          1                 100            101           1
```

because the one line of `event_master` matches both lines of `event`.

Then you are selecting from this table on this condition:

```
em.Id = e.event_master_id
AND
    (e.from_user_id = '100'
    OR
    e.to_user_id = 100)
AND 
e.status = 1
```

Well, the first part of the `AND` is true for both rows, because that was your condition for `INNER JOIN`. The third part is also true for both rows, because `e.status` is 1. The second part, which is the `OR` part, says `e.from_user_is = 100 OR blablabla`. Since `e.from_user_is = 100` is true for both rows, this part of the `AND` predicate is true too.

Therefore, you get all the three parts of the `AND` predicate true for both rows. As a result, `SELECT` returns both rows to you.

Now what you want is not really clear to me. If you want `from_user_id` to be equal to `to_user_id`, you should put `... AND e.from_user_id = e.from_user_id` in your `WHERE` predicate.

To part where you said *and if not then look for `to_user_id`* I didn't really get.